# Why isn't this game I made in python working correctly?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a 2d game but not in a normal way here is the code I have weird stuff happens when I try to go up or down, and I don't understand why it dose some weird things like going left and other things when I go left and am not on bottom row it goes down

```
import keyboard
import time
#split file by 0
d = []
a = open("Map.txt","r+", encoding="utf8")
a.write("""┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo │
│ o ┌────────────┐ o ┌────────────┐ o │
│ o └────────────┘ o └────────────┘ o │
│ ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo │
│ o ┌─┐ o ┌─────────────────┐ o ┌─┐ o │
│ o │ │ o └─────────────────┘ o │ │ o │
│ o │ │ ooooooooooooooooooooooo │ │ o │
│ o │ └───────┐ o ┌─┐ o ┌───────┘ │ o │
│ o └─────────┘ o │ │ o └─────────┘ o │
│ ooooooooooooooo │ │ ooooooooooooooo │
│ o ┌──┐ o ┌──────┘ └──────┐ o ┌──┐ o │
│ o └──┘ o └───────────────┘ o └──┘ o │
│ ooooooooooooooooo0ooooooooooooooooo │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘""")
#use this to make it a list
b = list(a)
for c in b:
    d += list(c)
#detect key press
true = 1
while true == 1:
    time.sleep(2)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("left"):
        e = d.index('0')
        if d[e-1] == "o" or d[e-1] == " ":
            d[e] = " "
            d[e-1] = '0'
    if keyboard.is_pressed("right"):
        e = d.index('0')
        if d[e+1] == "o" or d[e+1] == " ":
            d[e] = " "
            d[e+1] = '0'
    if keyboard.is_pressed("up"):
        e = d.index('0')
        if d[e-39] == "o" or d[e-39] == " ":
            d[e] = " "
            d[e-39] = '0'
    if keyboard.is_pressed("left"):
        e = d.index('0')
        if d[e+39] == "o" or d[e+39] == " ":
            d[e] = " "
            d[e+39] = '0'
    try:
        f = ''
        for i in d:
            f += i
        print(f)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: what do you think `b = list(a)` will do? You have variable `a` set to open a file.

Comment: I just tried what I found online, but it works, it splits by every character into a list

Comment: Are you taking into account the `' '` at the borders of the wall `│ ooooooooooooooooo0o`. You can see that you have a space before the border. So the `'0'` will end up going all the way to the wall. Then when you press up or down or right, it will start going into all those sections that don't have a wall like parts

Comment: You need to consider if you have reached any of those borders (2 positions) and check for `│ `  and  `─`

Comment: if d[e-1] == "o" or d[e-1] == " ":
this makes it only go if there is a ' ' or a 'o', I believe that's what you are asking